# Should Chinese text be grid aligned in game dialogs?

Tags: text, localization

Title says it all, should I have my text using a variable width font, or fixed width.  I didn't know if it is easier to read if its aligned on a grid?

Comment: Probably a better question for the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) or [Chinese Language and Usage](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange sites.

Comment: Aren't Chinese fonts always inherently monospaced?

Comment: @Kevin Chinese fonts [have half-width spaces](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%A8%E5%BD%A2%E5%92%8C%E5%8D%8A%E5%BD%A2). Japanese even has full-width (カタカナ) and half-width (ｶﾀｶﾅ) versions of the some of the same characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it the old-fashioned way, then yes, you can use it in a grid. But if you want to use any kind of variable or half-width characters, like writing 5 instead of ５, then you'll need to get off the grid. The characters are all the same width anyway so if you're not using any non-Asian characters then it should align by itself. I don't think having it not on a grid would make any difference in readability.

As a demonstration:

> 你好，我是中国人１２３|
>
> １２３４５６７８你好！|

Versus:

> 你好，我是中国人123|
>
> 12345678你好！|

The question of whether it *should* be in a grid is really up to you. If you're dealing with presenting data, like a statistics screen, then using a fixed width for all characters could make things easier. If you're just printing lines of text, on the other hand, it makes much less of a difference and you can choose freely, as you can find both ways in use.

Comment: Can you read Chinese?

Comment: I can read Japanese which has a fair bit of Chinese in it and *some* Chinese.

Comment: I have a block of text with numbers in it, all of the Asian characters are aligned, then where there are numbers mixed in it throws the rest of the alignment off for the row.

Comment: If you're concerned about maintaining the alignment then just use the full width characters, so instead of 12345 use １２３４５